# How to load an object as a property from TStringStream by ReadComponent method

Tags: c++

I want to pass an object with all attributes and owned objects in it from a Client side to a Server side with WriteComponent & ReadComponent methods.I tried many many times and read a lot stuff about it in sites and C++ builder help and finally I found out that the data must be __property in the published section of the class.otherwise when reading the content of the stream TReader Object fails to properly restore the class data.I made the data as __property like the code below and it is successful for data types like int or AnsiString or other types of primitive data.but my problem is here.the objects of the class like a TStringList is not loaded properly and the program rises an exception.my code is here:

Client side:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
MySecClass *BClass=new MySecClass(this);
BClass->List->Add(Edit->Text);
BClass->Size="Huge";
BClass->Length=100;
AnsiString Str;
TStringStream *SStr=new TStringStream(Str);
SStr->WriteComponent(BClass);
SStr->Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
IdTCPClient->Connect();
IdTCPClient->WriteInteger(SStr->DataString.Length());
IdTCPClient->Write(SStr->DataString);
IdTCPClient->Disconnect();
}
```

Server side:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::IdTCPServerExecute(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
int length=AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();
AnsiString Message=AThread->Connection->ReadString(length);
AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
TStringStream *SStr=new TStringStream(Message);
TComponent *MyObject=NULL;
MyObject=SStr->ReadComponent(NULL);
ListBox->Items->Add(((MySecClass*)MyObject)->List->Strings[0]);
}
```

MyClass Unit:

```
class MyClass : public TComponent{

__published:
__property AnsiString Size ={read=GetSize , write=SetSize ,stored=true};
__property int Length={read=GetLength ,write=SetLength ,stored=true};

private:
AnsiString FSize;
int FLength;

public:
__fastcall MyClass(TComponent* AOwner);
AnsiString __fastcall GetSize();
int __fastcall GetLength();
void __fastcall SetSize(AnsiString ASize);
void __fastcall SetLength(int ALength);

};

class MySecClass : public MyClass{

__published:
__property TStringList* List={read=FList ,write=SetList ,stored=true};

private:
TStringList* FList;

public:
__fastcall MySecClass(TComponent* AOwner);
void __fastcall SetList(TStringList* AList);
};

__fastcall MyClass::MyClass(TComponent* AOwner):TComponent(AOwner){
FSize="Empty";
FLength=0;
}

AnsiString __fastcall MyClass::GetSize(){
return FSize;
}

int __fastcall MyClass::GetLength(){
return FLength;
}

void __fastcall MyClass::SetSize(AnsiString ASize){
FSize=ASize;
}

void __fastcall MyClass::SetLength(int ALength){
FLength=ALength;
}

__fastcall MySecClass::MySecClass(TComponent* AOwner):MyClass(AOwner){
FList=new TStringList;
}

void __fastcall MySecClass::SetList(TStringList* AList){
FList=AList;
}
```

Keep in mind that I Registered the classes MyClass And MySecClass in the Projects.
Please help me to know where the problem is???
I realy need your help because this problem is related to my MS thesis

Answer (score 0):

In the SetList method try

```
FList->CommaText = AList->CommaText;
```

instead of assigning one pointer variable to another. This copies the contents and should work then. This way you can also use the abstract TStrings class instead of TStringList. But in the constructor you have to initialize it like `FList=(TStrings*)(new TStringList);`.